# Programming a UIDate Picker to be fixed at the bottom of the screen in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift5

I am trying to add a UIDatePicker to a set of text fields which are already present. I am unable to set the UI Date picker to the bottom of the screen even after trying all the solutions I see on StackOverflow. I am using the MVVM model and I have created a separate file for creating the Picker view.

```
class UAFieldDatePickerView: UIStackView {....}

extension UAFieldDatePickerView {
    @objc private func didTapDateView() {
        guard viewModel.state.value != .disabled else {
            return
        }
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 200)
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.UANeutralGray05
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.addSubview(datePicker)
    }

    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
    }
}
```

The problem I face is not being able to pin the DatePicker to the bottom of the screen. How Will I be able to ensure that the frame is always pinned to the bottom.

Comment: Instead of adding the picker as a View, set it as the `inputView` from every textField (`myField.inputView = datePicker`)

Comment: It's very hard (for me) to understand the issue with your screenshot. No downvoting, but based on the one answer suggesting subclassing `UIControl` and using frames(!) it sounds (again, to me) that you really haven't analyzed the actual issue enough to (1) ask a specific question about (2) something we can really duplicate. Maybe you could clarify? If it's layout - which your question title suggests, could you give us the layout code? If it's part of the screen shot that contains "Oh no! An error! What ever shall we do!" could you give more details to reproduce?

Comment: You are right, the image was misleading and unwanted too. Mine was all about Layouts. Basically the datePicker.frame which I used earlier doesn't really set the date picker at the bottom of the screen. How would I be able to pin the UIDatePicker view to the bottom of the screen. Calebs solution points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` descends from `UIControl`, which means it's also a subclass of `UIView`, and it follows the same rules that any other view does. If you want a date picker positioned at the bottom of the screen, then you need to put it there.

```
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 200)
```

Here you're setting the vertical position of the date picker to the screen height minus the height of the picker. But you're not adding the picker to the screen, you're adding it to `self`. If you want the picker to be positioned at the bottom of the view that you're adding it to, then you should calculate the height based on that view, not based on something else that might or might not have the same size. Since you're adding the picker to `self`, use `self.bounds.size.height` to calculate the position:

```
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height - 200, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 200)
```

If you want the picker to be at the bottom of the *screen*, then either take steps to ensure that the view that contains it is positioned at the bottom of the screen, or display the picker a different way. CZ54's suggestion in comments to use the picker as an input view is a good one; a more general way to do something similar is to present the date picker modally from the bottom of the screen.